# Check Excel file destination temp table in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have created ssis package to generate excel file dynamically from sql table.

But when I try to check whether that excel connection temp table if present or not using below query in sql task it gets failed syntax error

```
IF object_id(MyExcel) is not null

CREATE TABLE `MyExcel` (
    `CUSIP` varchar(50),
    `FaceAmount` decimal(18,4),
    `Portfolio` varchar(50),
    `PositionDate` DateTime,
    `PositionCost` decimal(18,6),
    `CurrentPrice` decimal(18,6)
)

else drop table MyExcel
```

ERROR :

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "IF object_id(MyExcel) is not null

CREATE TABLE `..." failed with the following error: "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Please advise?

I have tried with answer

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'MyExcel') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE MyExcel;
    END;

CREATE TABLE [MyExcel] 
(
    [CUSIP]         VARCHAR(50),
    [FaceAmount]    DECIMAL(18,4),
    [Portfolio]     VARCHAR(50),
    [PositionDate]  DATETIME,
    [PositionCost]  DECIMAL(18,6),
    [CurrentPrice]  DECIMAL(18,6)
);
```

But still getting same error for statements

```
 IF OBJECT_ID(N'MyExcel') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE MyExcel;
        END;
```

I'm using this query inside `SQL TASK` 
Connection type is `EXCEL`
[image]

Comment: You have to specify the table name inside the single quotes.

Comment: Do you mean excel sheet or SQL table?

Comment: Excel sheet table that we used in `excel destination`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't create an excel file with CREATE TABLE. If you come to think of excel file as database, the tables would be.. worksheets :).

To create an excel file, you'd Excel Connection Manager. You need to point it once to a template file, and after you set up excel destination with correct expressions, the file will be created. If it already exists, you just need to redirect the error.

And then you use Execute Sql to create the table (i.e. worksheet), of your desired structure.

Comment: hi i'm using Excel Connection Manager only but for mapping we need to create a table in excel destination editor

Comment: @ashuthinks Yes, I get it. But you don't create Excel file via CREATE TABLE. You create a worksheet with desired columns via CREATE TABLE in already existing excel file.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a combination of SQL-Server syntax (`OBJECT_ID('ObjectName')`) and MySQL syntax (back ticks for object names). I am assuming you are connecting to a SQL-Server database so you should qualify your object names with `[]`. e.g.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'MyExcel') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [MyExcel] 
        (
            [CUSIP]         VARCHAR(50),
            [FaceAmount]    DECIMAL(18,4),
            [Portfolio]     VARCHAR(50),
            [PositionDate]  DATETIME,
            [PositionCost]  DECIMAL(18,6),
            [CurrentPrice]  DECIMAL(18,6)
        );
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE MyExcel;
    END;
```

However, I believe your logic is flawed, your statement is saying "If the table exists, create it, if not drop it", so if it does already exist you will get an error saying the table already exists, if it doesn't then you will get an error saying you can't drop it because it doesn't exist. What you would really want is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'MyExcel') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [MyExcel] 
        ....
```

However, this still presents you with a problem, since if the table exists before the task is run, it won't after, if it doesn't exist before then it will be created, which means whether or not the table exists after the task completes is dependent on whether or not the table exists before. I would imagine you want to do something like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'MyExcel') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [MyExcel] 
        (
            [CUSIP]         VARCHAR(50),
            [FaceAmount]    DECIMAL(18,4),
            [Portfolio]     VARCHAR(50),
            [PositionDate]  DATETIME,
            [PositionCost]  DECIMAL(18,6),
            [CurrentPrice]  DECIMAL(18,6)
        );
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        TRUNCATE TABLE [MyExcel];
        -- If you don't want to truncate the table and want it with
        -- it's previous data in just remove the entire `else` clause
    END;
```

Or

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'MyExcel') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE MyExcel;
    END;

CREATE TABLE [MyExcel] 
(
    [CUSIP]         VARCHAR(50),
    [FaceAmount]    DECIMAL(18,4),
    [Portfolio]     VARCHAR(50),
    [PositionDate]  DATETIME,
    [PositionCost]  DECIMAL(18,6),
    [CurrentPrice]  DECIMAL(18,6)
);
```

i.e. after the task is run you will always have an table called MyExcel in the database, so you know it will be there when you get to the next step in your SSIS package.

**ADDENDUM**

As far as I know, you cannot use `IF` with an excel connection. There is an article [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1674/retrieve-excel-schema-using-sql-integration-services-ssis/) on querying the meta data from an excel workbook so you can check if a table exists. This is probably the technically correct way of doing it.

I was able to create a work around though, by having an `Execute SQL Task` with the following SQL:

```
DELETE  
FROM    MyExcel;
```

Then adding another `Execute SQL Task` to the On Error event handler to run:

```
CREATE TABLE MyExcel 
(
    CUSIP         VARCHAR(50),
    FaceAmount    DECIMAL(18,4),
    Portfolio     VARCHAR(50),
    PositionDate  DATETIME,
    PositionCost  DECIMAL(18,6),
    CurrentPrice  DECIMAL(18,6)
);
```

So if the table does not exists, the delete statement will throw an error, which will trigger the create table statement. Thus ensuring after the task has run the table `MyExcel` definitely exists.

*These tasks could be reversed, the result would be the same*

Comment: Updated question with image please advise , still getting same error for `IF` condition :(

Comment: In one case, (If Object_ID...) you are referencing SQL Syntax.  In the latter, the syntax (with the sideways single quote, the syntax refers to creating an empty Excel sheet.   I don't think you can combine both.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Execute SQL Task to the end of the control flow to Drop the Excel table(s) in the package.  This will leave the environment ready for the package to be processed again.